# I want to mock a server before bean creation in spring boot integration test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I am writing Integration tests in spring-boot.
One of my beans is using UrlResource("http://localhost:8081/test") for its creation.
I want to create a mock server, which will serve the above url with a mock response.
But I want this mock server to be created before any bean is initialized, as the mock server should be available to serve requests before the bean is initialized.

I have tried using the MockRestServiceServer in the @TestConfiguration

Following is the pseudo code which is failing:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestApiGatewayApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

    @TestConfiguration
    class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
            String mockKeyResponse = "{\"a\":\"abcd\"}";
            mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8081/test"))
                    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess(mockKeyResponse, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

            RestTemplateBuilder builder = mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
            when(builder.build()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
            return builder;
        }

    }


}
```

Following is the sample code for creation of bean which is to be tested.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public SampleBean sampleBean(){
        Resource resource = new UrlResource("");
        // Some operation using resource and create the sampleBean bean
        return sampleBean;
    }
}
```

Using the above approach I am getting
" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"
error as it is not able to access the http://localhost:8081/test endpoint.

Comment: You are constructing a new mock here and not returning your constructed mock `return mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class).build();` looks funky.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Sorry about the Edited code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@InjectMocks`.

Reference : [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) and [Explaination with example.](https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-mock-injectmocks/)

Comment: Not working using @InjectMocks. I have to create the object and have the url ready before bean initialization starts, or before the specific bean is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by creating a MockServiceServer in the testConfiguration.
Sample code is as follows.

```
@TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
            String mockKeyResponse = "{\"a\":\"abcd\"}";
            mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8081/test"))
                    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess(mockKeyResponse, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

            RestTemplateBuilder builder = mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
            when(builder.build()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
            return builder;
        }

    }
```

Then in the class BeanConfig where I needed to use this I have autowired using constructor injection, so that RestTemplate will be created before bean of BeanConfig class is created.
Following is how I did it.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public BeanConfig(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SampleBean sampleBean(){
        Resource resource = new UrlResource("");
        // Some operation using resource and create the sampleBean bean
        return sampleBean;
    }
}
```